# Center 7 col-xs in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 7 col-xs (12-7=5) and i can't center this.

```
.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

didin't work

```
    .col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right:-4px;
    }
```

work but i can't use margin for only one col-xs ;/

Comment: Can you show your HTML too? At least the col layout

Comment: At [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) you can set up the number of columns of your grid system. If 12 is not good for you, set another value, like 13, so 13-7 = 6 ...

Answer (score 1):

**7 equal centered columns** is hard using standard Bootstrap since 7 is not an even factor of 12. The only way is using nesting, offsets or custom CSS. If you want to avoid a custom grid (customizing with LESS or SASS).

Here are some options...

**7 centered col-{x}-1 using nesting & offset:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[Demo & other examples for **Bootstrap 3**](http://www.bootply.com/td5tnsAgoR)

And in case your considering Bootstrap 4, odd columns are easier now thanks to the flexbox based grid: 
[5,7 or 9, etc.. columns with **Bootstrap 4**](http://www.codeply.com/go/NxDFoUhYh5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flexbox` to achieve it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">.</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And styles

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```